# Теория 6-ти рукопожатий. VK, список друзей

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Решил как минимум помечтать, как максимум сделать программу.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы собрать список друзей, друзей-друзей, друзей-друзей-друзей и с указанным уровнем вложенности продолжать. Примерно прикинул как это должно выглядеть в базе данных. Остановился по нехватке знаний для написания программы по работе с ВКонтактом для получения сей информации.

С чего начать изучение? Приличные знания шарпа, но никогда не лазил в вебинтерфейсы. Парсинг страниц неверное не лучший вариант, скорее всего использовать лучше API контакта. Где почитать это все? и вообще реально ли так далеко ползать по друзьям друзей?

Бонусом будет, если можно вытащить аватар "друга" и описание его "интересы, группы".

PS: Может зря мучаюсь и уже есть что-то подобное в исходном коде?.. 
PPS: В планах после сбора информации сделать поиск и графическое отображение всех связей. Ведь реально прикольно посмотреть, при знакомстве с человеком, а нет ли у нас с ним знакомых через "6ть рукопожатий"? :-)

Comment: [VK для разработчиков...][1]


  [1]: http://vk.com/dev

Comment: Здесь человек проделал почти тоже самое, что Вы хотите проделать. [Теория шести рукопожатий: еще одно подтверждение](http://habrahabr.ru/post/132558/)

Comment: Спасибо, это то что мне нужно.

Comment: Используйте [VKNET](https://vknet.github.io/vk/) фреймворк. Он много чего умеет и значительно облегчает жизнь при работе с ВК на C#.

Comment: где то я видел грант на эту тему, интересно, вы это для себя делаете?

Comment: Прошло уже много времени, за это время уже появилось [приложение](https://vk.com/6hands_app) с данной идеей. Возможно, кому-то поможет при поиске